# SET-COOKIE problems with a backend nodejs and frontend Angular deployed on Vercel

Tags: node.js, angular, vercel

I'm trying to send a cookie from my backend "myback.vercel.app" to the front "myfront.vercel.app" using cookie-session of nodejs. But the problem is that the cookies are present in response SET-COOKIE but looking at Application>cookies from chrome, they are not there.
Can anyone help me please?

this is my cookie config:

```
app.use(cookieSession({
name: process.env.COOKIE_NAME,
secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
sameSite:'none',
httpOnly: true,
secureProxy:true}));
```

Comment: Does it work locally?

Comment: yes, it works in local serve